# Detemine root parent folder of a message with Outlook REST API

Tags: outlook-restapi, office365-restapi

I am using Outlook REST API V2 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations)

1. Is there a way to determine the root parent folder of a message without making subsequent requests to get the parent of the parent of the parent, etc.. of the message folder?
   In my case I would like to know if a message is "deleted", by finding out if the message is anywhere under the DeletedItems hierarchy.
2. Related to this - Is there a way to get all messages under a folder regardless of where in the sub-folders of the folder the message is, without making separate requests to traverse the sub-folders hierarchy?

Thanks for your time to anyone willing to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, there isn't any direct way by just looking at the message entities. You could sync the mail folder hierarchy down locally to your client, then essentially construct a list of IDs for the Deleted Items and any folders under it, then compare IDs in your message list. You'd have to be sure to [keep the folder hierarchy table on your client in sync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#synchronize-folder-hierarchy).
2. No, there is no deep traversal. If you get the `/messages` collection from a folder, it's only immediate children. If you get `/me/messages`, it's messages from all folders in the mailbox (which is more than what you're asking I think).